# Countability of $\{S\subseteq \Bbb Q:\;\text{S is finite}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

I was given the following problem on a test and provided the proof below. My professor says there is an error in my logic (which I'll identify later) but I respectfully disagree and am looking for a second opinion.

I'm asked to consider the following set $A$ and prove that $|A|=|\Bbb Q|$.

$$A=\{S\subseteq \Bbb Q:\;\text{S is finite}\}$$

To show that $|A|\ge|\Bbb Q|$, I said consider the following subset $B$ of $A$:

$$B=\{S\subseteq \Bbb Q: |S|=1\}$$

The set $B$ consists of elements which are sets of cardinality $1$. This means $\forall\;x\in \Bbb Q$, $\{x\}\in B$. Since $B\subseteq A$, $|A|\ge|\Bbb Q|$. She gave credit for this part, but the next was where we disagreed.

To show $|A|\not>|\Bbb Q|$, I offered the following:

Consider a finite subset of $\Bbb Q$ with cardinality $\le n$. This subset is comparable to an ordered pair in $\Bbb Q^n$. E.g. if $n=4$, we have the following:

$$\{a,b,c,d\}\text{ is comparable to } (a,b,c,d) \text{ in }\Bbb Q^4$$

For subsets of cardinality $p$ less than four, I said one could simply repeat the last entry $n-p$ times since sets require unique elements but ordered pairs do not.

$$\{a,b\}\text{ is comparable to }(a,b,b,b)\text{ in }\Bbb Q^4$$

In each case , the ordered pair in $\Bbb Q^n$ is unique, implying injectivity.

Thus, my solution simply found an injection from $A$ to $\Bbb Q^n$ and utilised the fact that the Cartesian product of countable sets is countable to show that $|A|\le|\Bbb Q|\implies|A|=|\Bbb Q|$.

However, my professor claimed that this does not necessarily hold for sufficiently large $n$. She compared my work to the false proof that the sum of naturals is finite because each time you add the next natural to the previous sum, you're adding a finite number to a finite sum.

I disagree because no matter how large $n$, this is still comparable to $\Bbb Q^n$.

I normally would never have the confidence to disagree with her as she's an extremely good professor, but I feel like my approach is valid and want to see if anyone else does.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you have a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{Q}^n$. Which $n$ are you taking here?

Comment: seems right to me. I think the main reason your proof is correct is because you are only taking finite subsets.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi corrected it to injection. Combined with the first part this implies that it is also a bijection

Comment: How would you map a set of size $n+1$ into $\mathbb{Q}^n$?

Comment: @Zestylemonzi you wouldn't, you'd map it to $\Bbb Q^{n+1}$

Comment: But then you're mapping $A$ into $\cup_n \mathbb{Q}^n$.

Comment: My point is that your map doesn't map $A$ into $\mathbb{Q}^n$ for some fixed $n$. Your argument can probably be extended to work, you just need to use the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: ^^^ I thought I did just that in the fourth paragraph from the bottom.

Comment: It looks like you're using the fact that a finite product of countable sets is countable. This is not enough in this case.

Comment: I think the confusion is that you are considering some fixed $n$ and I am referring to it as some arbitrarily large natural.

Comment: The function you use to map sets to tuples in $\mathbb Q^n$ is not a function at all. The sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{3,2,1\}$ are the same set, but are mapped to $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,2,1)$, resp., which are different.

Comment: @sranthrop That's irrelevant, I'm not claiming that this is a surjection, only an injection.

Comment: You are claiming that it is an injection, which is, per definition, an injective function. Moreover, there is no "arbitrary large natural".

Comment: What you could do, however, is to define your mapping the other way round. A tuple $(1,2,3)$ is mapped to the set $\{1,2,3\}$. This would be a well-defined function, which is surjective.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I should have included the the stipulation that elements are arranged a certain way.

However, I don't see why you have a problem with $n$. Since the subsets are finite, they will all have cardinality equal to some integer $n$. In which case, I said to consider $\Bbb Q^n$.

Comment: @LanierFreeman sranthrop is claiming (convincingly) that the relationship is one to many, hence not an injection. He said $\{1,2,3\}$ can map to both $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,2,1)$.

Comment: @Χpẘ I agree with his claim, it was a great point.

Comment: Your logic is faulty because you are saying each  union is finite but you have an infinite number of unions.  If you can prove/argue that an infinite countable union of countable sets is countable, then you are fine.  But you can't claim such a thing without verification.

Comment: At no point do you have an injection of all of $A$ into any one $\mathbb Q^n.$

Comment: @fleablood My proof didn't require the union of any sets. Any set of cardinality less than $n$ in the proof can be expressed as a *tuple in $\Bbb Q^n$ using a process I outlined halfway through.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is countable.... Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime. If $S$ is countable, let $f:S\to \mathbb N$ be injective. For $s\in S$ let 
 $g(s)=p_{f(s)}.$ ...For finite $T\subset S,$ let $ h(T)=1$ if $T$ is empty; if $T\ne \phi$ let $h(T)=\prod _{t\in T}g(t).$ ...Then $h$ is injective.

Comment: "any set of cardinality less than n in the proof can be expressed as a -tuple in Qn using a process I outlined halfway through."  Well, that's your error right there.  The set A is not any one of the set of n-tuples.  It's the set of *all* -tuples.  You've proven the set of n-tuples are countable and the set n+1 tuples and the set of on m-tuples are countable but you haven't addressed *anything* about the set A itself-- the set of all tuples of *any* size.  You've only done tuples of *specific* sizes.  That is *exactly* the same argument that $\mathbb N$ is finite because all {1,2,....n} are.

Comment: "Since the subsets are finite, they will all have cardinality equal to some integer n".  Which integer $n$?  If you say they all have cardinality equal or less than 5137, what if I find a set with cardinality 5138.?  So there is not "some" integer n that they "all" have cardinality less .  They *each* have cardinality less than an n, but they don't *all* have cardinality less than the *same* n.  So the set of ALL of them, does not map into some $Q^n$ because some sets will be *BIGGER* than n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a complete answer, but I would like to point out two main issues that I see in your proof (which rests on some good ideas, though!).

First, as mentioned in the comments, the mapping you describe, is not a function, since two equal sets like $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{3,2,1\}$ are mapped to two different tuples, namely $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,2,1)$, respectively. Thus, as you suggested, you have to identify equal sets somehow. For example, by ordering the elements. The mathematical concept behind that is called "equivalence relation". To avoid this, you can simply go the other way round and define a surjective function by mapping a tuple to the set of its elements.

The second problem is the $n$. I think what you wanted to do is something like this: Fix $n\in\mathbb N$ and define $A_n:=\{S\subset\mathbb Q\ |\ |S|=n\}$ (you can also use $|S|\leq n$, the result is the same). Then, with one of the abovementioned methods, you show that $|A_n|\leq|\mathbb Q|$. Although this is true for any $n$, you now have to say what each individual $A_n$ has to do with $A$. You cannot say something like $A_n=A$, because $n$ is an arbitrary large natural whatever. You can pick arbitrary large $n$, but once such an $n$ is picked, it is and stays a finite (possibly very large but still finite) natural number until the end of days. To finish we could do something like this: Since $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ is a countable union of countable sets we conclude $|A|\leq|\mathbb Q|$.

I hope that this helps a little, and I think that last point is what your professor meant when she complained about the "large" $n$. If you have any questions, pls don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can argue as follows: enumerate the rationals in some way $\left \{ r_1,r_2,\cdots  \right \}$ and list the primes in order $\left \{ p_1,p_2,\cdots  \right \}=\left \{ 2,3,\cdots  \right \}.$ Now, $A=\bigcup _nA_n$ where $A_n=\{S\subseteq \Bbb Q: |S|=n\}.$

Write $r_i=\frac{s_i}{t_i}:s_i,t_i\in \mathbb N$ in lowest terms. Notice that if $r_i\neq r_j$ then either $s_i\neq s_j$ or $t_i\neq t_j.$ Then, $\left ( \frac{s_{i_1}}{t_{i_1}},\cdots, \frac{t_{i_n}}{t_{i_n}} \right )\mapsto p_{i_1}^{s_{i_1} t_{i_1}}\times\cdots \times p_{i_n}^{s_{i_n} t_{i_n}}$ injects $A_n$ into $\mathbb N$ and it follows that $A$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

"Thus, my solution simply found an injection from A to $Q^n$ "

No, it didn't.

How do you map $S$ so that $|S| = n+1$ into $\mathbb Q^{n}$?

You've only mapped all $S$ so that $|S| = 1$ to $\mathbb Q^1$ and all $S$ so that $|S| \le n$ into $\mathbb Q^n$ but you sure as heck haven't shown that you can map all $S$ so that $|S|$ is finite into some $\mathbb Q^n$.

What if $|S|$ is much much larger than your $n$?

You've proven that $A_n = \{S \subset \mathbb Q| |S| \le n\}$ is countable for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

But $A =\{S \subset \mathbb Q| S \text{ is finite}\}\ne S_n$ for any $n$.

This is *exactly* the same as proving that $A_n = \{k \in \mathbb N| k \le n\}$ is finite so $A = \{k \in \mathbb N \}$ is finite.

You *need* to argue that $A = \cup_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n$ and that the countable union of countable sets is countable.